# How to send a string in a hyperlink to fill a field in a form?

Tags: php, html, string, forms, hyperlink

I need to have a value in a text field auto filled with a pre-selected variable. Can the string be sent through a hyperlink and be filled in to a html form `"text"` area?

```
    <form method="POST" action='googler.php'>
    <label for="query">Query</label><br/>
    <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" /><br /><br />
```

In other words can the `"value"` be filled with something else If I have used a link to get to this page?

Comment: `<textarea><?php echo $_GET['queryname'] ?></textarea>`?

Comment: @MarcB — Danger! XSS!

Comment: The `for` attribute for a label references the **id** of the form control it is associated with. Your input doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in a URL will cause a browser to auto-populate a field.

Any part of a URL (although a query string parameter is traditional) can be used by server side code to set the `value` attribute value when the HTML is generated.

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['foo']); ?>"
```

Comment: So, can I create something like this from the other page that passes the value?  `echo (<a href = 'googler.php?query='.$suggestion[$ss_count].</a>'<br>');`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can put the value you want to fill in the URL, like: `www.yourdomain.com?myval=test`, and then just get that value with `$_GET['myval']`

Comment: Sounds like this might just be what I need. Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: If I understand you right. I can create a hyperlink that holds a value and then `GET` the value in to `value` field?